# Windows Media Encoder installation issue

Tags: windows, sdk, media, encoder

I have a program written in C# and dependent on Windows Media Encoder 9 Series SDK. In order for my program to run on other target machines, I have to install the whole Windows Media Encoder on target machines.

My question is, I want to reduce the overhead of installation the whole Windows Media Encoder on target machine, are there any ways to just copy/register some DLLs on target machine to reduce the overhead of installation of the whole Windows Media Encoder?

EDIT: I have a new idea and ask for advice, is it possible to create one installation application to install Windows Media Encoder and my application together -- e.g. in one installation wizard?

thanks in advance, 
George

Answer (score 2):

You could try reducing your dependencies to the [WMF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384477.aspx).  Many computers I've seen lately come with WME installed, though.

Comment: I need to use features in Windows Media Encoder to record audio/video/screen, and I do not think WMF supports such features.